# Julia programming language

Tags: python, r, julia

I've heard a lot of buzz for Julia programming language and how *it's the future of AI*. Should I buy into the hype and start learning Julia? Or do you think its better to stick to a better established language (e.g. python). What are the pros and cons of Julia compared to other languages aimed towards data science (python, R, etc.)?

Comment: Language is Just a Tool!